# Can you export xcor and ycor information from netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to export xcor and ycor locations for one turtle. i need to get each coordinate every time the turtle moves to a new patch.

Is it also possible to read these values back in to netlogo to influence other turtles?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "export"?  Do you want to write the coordinates to a file and then read them back into a subsequent run of the model, or do you simply want to save the coordinate history of the turtle as the simulation runs and make it available to other turtles within the same simulation?

Comment: I want to be able to write them out and then read them back in to a later simulation. I am making improvement to the AI for the built in pac-man game and Im trying to see if i can make the ghosts read through old play through to predict the players moves.

Comment: So you can write all the coordinates out at the end of the simulation?  Or do you need to write out each coordinate at each move?

Comment: i need each coordinate at each move, to help predict the path the player takes, but if thats not possible i should be able to edit the file at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code might get you started.  The tracked turtle writes a list to a file at each step that contains the tick number and its coordinates.  You may not need the tick number, and of course you could add any other information about the turtle that you want to the list.

```
globals [track-me]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 5
  set track-me one-of turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to go

ask turtles [
  forward random 10
]
ask track-me [
  file-open "mytrack.txt"
  file-print (list ticks pxcor pycor)
  file-close
]
tick
end
```

Hope this helps,
Charles